# Why google index the pages that has been blocked on robots.txt?

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot, robots.txt

I found this very interesting.
I already blocked those pages via robots.txt but it keeps on showing on my Search Console for Smartphone.
Does adding this:

```
User-agent: Googlebot-mobile 
Allow: /*?variant=*
```

will make the error disappear?

The general robots.txt is:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*?variant=*
```

Comment: Search console data is not real time, they might showing your 1 month old data, it will be great if you test those URL on live Google search.

Comment: What section of Google Search Console are they appearing in?